# how to do Object detection in opengl Android?

Tags: android, events, opengl-es, touch, object-detection

I've started with OpenGl es for Android since 2 weeks and after trying 3D examples I'm stuckup at obect detection.
Basically mapping between x,y coordinates of screen to x,y,z of  3d space and vice a versa.

I came across :

**GLU.gluProject(objX, objY, objZ, model, modelOffset, project, projectOffset, view, viewOffset, win, winOffset);**

**GLU.gluUnProject(winX, winY, winZ, model, modelOffset, project, projectOffset, view, viewOffset, obj, objOffset);**

but i failed to understand that **How do I use them exactly**?

Thanks in advance if you can elaborate with suitable example. :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you have your matrices ready, you can do this:

```
float[] modelView = float[16];
float[] projection = float[16];
float[] view = {0, 0, 640, 480}; // viewport
float x = mouseX, y = mouseY, z = -1; 
// those are the inputs

float[] pos = new float[4]; 

GLU.gluUnProject(x, y, z, 
                modelView, 0, 
                projection, 0, 
                world.view().get_size(), 0, 
                pos, 0);

System.out.println("position of mouse in 3D is (" + pos[0] + ", " + pos[1] + ", " + pos[2] + ")");
```

If you want to select objects, you call gluUnProject() twice, once with z = -1 and once with z = 1. That gives you mouse positions at the near and far planes. Subtract them to get a view direction, use the first as an origin, and you have got yourself a nice raytracing task (object selection).

Comment: its an old answer but still if you can please tell me in opengl es 2 how we can get current model view matrix when we have applied projection and other rotation/translation transformations ?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal as far as I know, in ES 2 there is no way how to get the matrices from OpenGL, as the matrix stack was deprecated (and thus there is no longer any "current" matrix). However, you as programmer, need to specify those matrices to the shader as a uniform - so you already have these matrices in the first place. If your question is about how to decompose your MVP to modelview and projection, the answer is "you don't". You just apply all the linear transformations in one matrix (modelview) and the projection transromation in the other matrix (projectio). MVP is their product.