# Accessing project and model view matrices in opengl es 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm converting screen coordinates to world coordinates in opengl es 2.0 using

```
GLU.gluUnProject(winX, winY, winZ, model, modelOffset, project, projectOffset, view, viewOffset, obj, objOffset)
```

However, I'm unsure on how to retrieve the model view and project matrices. All the examples I've found only apply to opengl es 1.0 and 1.1. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: When working with opengles 2 in Android you keep track of your matrices yourself, usually as a couple of float[]. If you calculate them directly in the shader, I don't think that you can get them.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if GLU.gluUnProject() is even available to an opengl es 2.0 context.

Comment: no, it is not available, as Jave stated, OpenGL es 2.0 you have to take care of the matrices yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course this is possible in OpenGL ES 2.0. The only difference is that you don't have to pull the matrices using glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, array), but you have the matrices calculated in your code because OpenGL ES 2.0 no longer has functions such as glRotatef() glTranslate() etc. That's why you use Android class called Matrix which can do these calculations for you. It's very simple to pass your matrices to gluUnProject() then.

See [how to do Object detection in opengl Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486421/how-to-do-object-detection-in-opengl-android/8975555#8975555).

Comment: True, but apparently the OP is not aware of the Matrix class :)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html